# How to make IntelliJ Project Files Respect Maven Profile

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-profiles

I have imported a maven project which uses profiles in to IntelliJ. Under the maven projects window I see the profiles and see all of my projects listed correctly. When I select a profile it **does** update the dependencies under the projects with profiles defined. The problem seems to be that IntelliJ **does not** actually update its project files (*.iml files) with these updated dependencies.

The problem I'm having is that when I run the application through IntelliJ it does not run with the correct classpath because the iml file hasn't been updated with the correct dependencies for the active profile.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this just not possible to have IntelliJ use dependencies only defined under a profile?

Answer (score 1):

After switching to new profile you sometimes have to force synchronization:

Right click your `.iml` file in project browser and choose `Synchronize iml` option. For multi-module project it could be required to sync both parent and specific module.

p.s. I've just tested it in 14.1.2 Community Edition.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Do you know of any way to debug what is happening? If I remove the profile section from the pom file then the iml file is recreated as expected.

Comment: Nope, I don't know how to debug it. However you can use local history of iml file to see when exactly it's changed.